# How do I link to the English version of a site for search engines?

Tags: javascript, search, web, indexing, multilingual

I have a single page website in my native language and also an English version of this particular webpage. The default page is in my native language and has an URL: url.com. The English version is at url.com/en.

I also have a droplist with languages and use JS to set window.location to /en on change of the value in the droplist.

However, in this way the English version doesn't get indexed in major engines (google, bing).

I tried to add couple of links in a div with "display:hidden" but it didn't help to resolve the issue.

So the question is how to make the English version indexable from search engines. Is it possible without visible links?

Comment: Use a `<ul>` of proper links instead of a `<select>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can show search engines you have this content using sitemap.xml.

If you are using Wordpress, there's good plugins that does it like: WP SEO Yoast.

If not, you can do it "manually" on: http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/